# How can add relative href from multi url?

Tags: html

Home page of my web has 2 url:
`https://test/demo1/` or `https://test/demo1/home`

In home page i link to other page:

```
<a href="carts" >Link 1</a>
```

If i run home page is : `https://test/demo1/` link open is `https://test/carts`

If i run home page is : `https://test/demo1/home` link open is `https://test/demo1/carts`

How can set  relative `href`  of tag `a`, to always open link `https://test/demo1/carts`?

Comment: It can not be achieved by relative url my friend.  You have to go with the Absolute URL

Comment: can i use js to replace it?

Comment: @DT yes you can

Comment: `<head><base href='https://test/demo1/' /></head>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just call a function to add the attr or using `jQuery` to update the href

```js
function cartBtn(){
 var currURL = window.location.href;
  var link  = document.getElementById("cartLink"); //test/demo1/home// you a to cart
  if(currURL.indexOf("home") < 0){
    window.location = currURL+"/home/cart" ;
  }else {
    window.location = currURL+"/home";
  }
}
```

```html
<a  id="cartLink" href="#" onclick="cartBtn()"> click me </a>
```

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to fix this would be to have the URL you don't want redirect to your normal URL. Add the following, changing what you want where I have pointed:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="3; url="file.html" />
                                            ^^^^^^^^^
```

This is a commonly used element, I personally use this a lot in my website.
Just ask if any bit is unclear. But before you do, look here:

`http-equiv`: This essentially says that this element redirects the page.
`content`: The number of seconds until the redirect (`3`) and the page to redirect to (`file.html`)